# Apache Ant - как переименовать файлы?

Tags: ant, java

Допустим у меня в папке

```
temp/flash/... <- флеш файлы с расширением .swf
```

как мне с помощью ант, получить список этих файлов, переименовать их, скажем в

```
flash_name.swf -> flash_name-1-.swf
flash_name2.swf -> flash_name2-1-.swf
...
```

и закинуть в папку

```
temp/flash1/...
```

Подскажите! Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так

```
<copy todir="${temp.dir}/flash1" verbose="true" overwrite="true">
  <fileset dir="${temp.dir}/flash" />
  <globmapper from="*.swf" to="*-1.swf" />
</copy>
```

Почитайте про [glob-mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#glob-mapper) и про [regexp-mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#regexp-mapper)

Comment: Блин, как всё просто. Спасибо!

Comment: Ant очень силён, но не всегда очевиден...

Comment: просто тут совсем другой подход к программированию, но когда привыкнешь... начинаешь понимать что этот муравей и правда может свернуть горы :) 

гуглить: Императивное и декларативное программирование